# DIV is not getting fix in parent div

Tags: css, html

I am using three divs div1 as parent, and div2, div3 as child.
Here div2 and div3 are set as left and right float property...
these two divs are not getting fix in parent div..
Need help ????

```
   <div class="blogMain">
        <div class="blogLeftBlock">
          block1
        </div>

        <div class="blogRightBlock">
        vlock2
        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS classes are**

```
.blogMain
{

    width: 95%;
    height: auto;

}

.blogLeftBlock
{

    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    float:left;
}

.blogRightBlock
{
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;

}
```

Comment: can you make it little bit in detail?

Comment: I am using div1 as parent .. in div1 I am using div2 and div3, these two divs are as child and div2, div3 are set as left and right float property ..
I want div2 and div3 should be fix in div1 that is not happening ..
child divs become overflow to div1.

Comment: edit your question and add some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix the `div2` and `div3` inside `div1`, you have to give the `div1` a `width` greater than `750px`

html

```
<div class="blogMain">
  <div class="blogLeftBlock"> block1 </div>
  <div class="blogRightBlock"> vlock2 </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.blogMain {
    width: 760px;
    height: auto;
}
.blogLeftBlock {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    float:left;
}
.blogRightBlock {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
}
```

you better check this article CSS Floats 101, pretty useful http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101

Comment: there is height problem and i can not fix the height of the div1 .. it is set to <b>auto</b>

Comment: add this <div style="clear:both"></div> after div3

Comment: thanks sobin problem has been solved .. 
by the way can you explain how it works ?plz

Comment: its called clearing floats,explained here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html